# How to call ManagementObject with more than one parameter?

Tags: c#, wmi

What's the right syntax to get a `BcdObject` using `ManagementObject`? for single parameters I use:

```
var obj = new ManagementObject(@"root\WMI", string.Format("BcdObject.Id = '{0}'"), null);
```

But I'm not sure how to add additional parameters (is it `AND`, or `,`, or something else?), something like:

```
var bcdObj = new ManagementObject(@"root\WMI",
    string.Format("BcdObject.Id = '{0}' AND BcdObject.StoreFilePath = '{1}'",
        "{current}", ""),
    null);
```

Comment: It's supposed to be 'AND'. Does it not work?

Comment: Nope, @bokibeg, but now at least I know it's not from this reason...

Comment: Try this path `"root\\WMI:BcdObject.Id=\"" + bcdId + "\",StoreFilePath=\"\""`

Comment: @bokibeg, it worked. And I reduced it to this: `"BcdObject.Id='{current}',StoreFilePath=''"` apparently the spaces were the hitch. Thank you! Please post an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: @bokibeg - also, the class name must appear only once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be the way to go:

```
var bcdId = "{current}";
var sfp = "";
var obj = new ManagementObject(
    "root\\WMI:BcdObject.Id=\"" + bcdId + "\",StoreFilePath=\"" + sfp + "\"");
```

Note that even if you merely put a space after the comma it won't work. Good luck!

You can pass the filter string as a second parameter in the constructor (like in your original code) but same rules apply - **no spaces**.